# Can I make a javascript function listening for two events? MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-events

I have the following two functions which are fired on different events:

```
$('.CCB').change(function (event) {
        var matches = [];
        $(".CCB:checked").each(function () {
            matches.push(this.value);
        });
        alert(matches);

    });
```

which is called when a check box item is checked and

```
$('#textBox').keydown(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            var st = document.getElementById("textBox").value
            if (code != 8) // if backspace is hit don't add it to the search term
            {
                st = st + String.fromCharCode(code);

            } 
            else
            {
                st = st.substr(0, st.length - 1)

            }

        });
```

which is fired when the user types in a text box. Can I unite them in some way so when any of the actions is fired (either check box check or text box keydown) to get both the array with check box values and the string from the text box, so after that I can perform some custom logic on them?

Comment: Why don't you put your logic which is 'common' to both events in a function and call that from the event handlers?

Comment: well there isn't any common logic in the two events. I just want to get the result from both of them when only one of them is called.

Comment: If there's no common logic then what is the "result"? Unrelated to your question, you can use `e.which` directly: jQuery normalises it for you so you don't have to test `e.keyCode`. Also your `st = st + ...` seems to assume that all keystrokes will add to the _end_ of the string, but what if the user edits the _middle?_

Comment: nice point about editing the middle! and for the result the checkbox event returns an array and the text box handler returns a string. At the end I just want obtain both of them( string, array) on any of the two actions.

Comment: @user1237359 Again the idea would be to use functions. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the logics for both events into functions and then call those functions. For eg.

```
function checkbox(){
  // logic for your operations on checkboxes
}

function keydown(){
   // logic for your operations on keydown in textbox
}
```

And then in your event handlers

```
var resultFromCheckboxLogic = checkbox();
var resultFromKeydownLogic = keydown();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/92/

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    var whole_array = []
    var tex_field_value = [];
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        tex_field_value.push($(this).val())
    });
    var check_box_value=[];
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked') == true){
            check_box_value.push($(this).val())
        }
    });
    whole_array = tex_field_value+","+check_box_value
    alert(whole_array)
});
```

This will work on every change of input fields.

Let me know if i understood your requirement correct or not.

Comment: almost. The only thing I need to change in your solution is listen for textbox.keydown instead of change